# Get month name from a date column

Tags: sql

We have a date column name called `"bus_date"` on a table called `"wmw_st_bte"`. The date format looks like this when we run an SQL query 
`(select bus_date from wmw_st_bte bet)`: "28/JUN/04". We would like to get total sales summarized by month from this table. So the result should look something like this.

```
Month: January 2004  or JAN 04 Sales: 10000
Month: February 2004 or FEB 04 Sales: 15000
```

So basically we need the right query to get the summarized month name from the date column "bus_date". Could someone please help?

We tried the following query however its giving us the following format under month column instead of month name:

month: 1 Sales: 10000

month: 2 Sales: 20000

Any clue how i can get the month name and year please?

Query we used:

```
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM bus_date) AS month
, SUM (sales) AS sales

FROM wmw_st_bte

GROUP BY
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM bus_date)

ORDER BY
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM bus_date)
```

Comment: Using SQL or MYSQL?

Comment: hi @reds its SQL thanks.

Comment: do you have a sample to your date from db?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language used by **all** relational databases. It is not a specific DBMS product.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like

```
select EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM bus_date ) , 
sum(sales) as sales
from wmw_st_bte
group by EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM bus_date )
```

Comment: i was able to fix the issue by putting SELECT to_char(bus_date,'MON-YYYY') in my query, thanks @Utsav

Answer (score 0):

Here an idea how to query it.
You can try it like this, (using SQL SERVER)

```
SELECT  SUM(Sales) Sales,cMonthYear
FROM    (
        SELECT Sales,(DATENAME(month,bus_date) + ' ' +CAST(YEAR(bus_date) AS VARCHAR(4))) cMonthYear,
               MONTH(bus_date) nMonth,YEAR(bus_date) nYear
        FROM wmw_st_bte
        )A
GROUP BY cMonthYear,nMonth,nYear
ORDER BY nYear,nMonth
```

I included the month and year on the initial / inner SELECT statement so I can arrange / sort the final result.

If you want to query it using date range [Start Date] and [End Date]. You can insert a WHERE clause on inner query like this.

```
SELECT  SUM(Sales) Sales,cMonthYear
FROM    (
        SELECT Sales,(DATENAME(month,bus_date) + ' ' +CAST(YEAR(bus_date) AS VARCHAR(4))) cMonthYear,
               MONTH(bus_date) nMonth,YEAR(bus_date) nYear
        FROM wmw_st_bte
        WHERE bus_date BETWEEN [Start Date] AND [End Date]
        )A
GROUP BY cMonthYear,nMonth,nYear
ORDER BY nYear,nMonth
```

Comment: thanks @Leo for the quick response however it didn't actually work. can i ask why did u use the n, c before Sales and MonthYear for?  nSales,cMonthYear)

Comment: its a prefix for columns I use to easily identify if the data type on the columns were text / character if (c), and numeric (n). Sorry, I did not notice your sample script. I edited my answer, you can try it again if you like, by the way what was the error.

Comment: Thanks again @Leo, i was able to fix the issue by putting SELECT 
  to_char(bus_date,'MON-YYYY') in my query :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by putting to_char function:

SELECT 
  to_char(bus_date,'MON-YYYY') AS month_year
, SUM (sales) AS sales

FROM wmw_st_bte

GROUP BY
  bus_date

ORDER BY
  bus_date